# Angular: Is this statement about change detection running when @Input is changed, correct?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

[This](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/) site says:

> In the default change detection strategy, Angular will run the change
> detector any time @Input() data is changed or modified

But in reality, change detection is triggered only on the following three conditions (as the same site says a little before):

> - any browser event (click, keyup, etc.)
> - getInterval() and setTimeout()
> - HTTP requests via XMLHttpRequest

What I understand is that change detection is triggered only in the above three cases and then Angular checks if the data present in template bindings has changed or not. If it has changed, it re-renders the view for that component. I'm assuming that if the binding is to a property in a child component, then that child component's UI will also be re-rendered if that binding is being used inside the child component's template.

So (unlike the statement at the start), change detection is NOT run when `@Input` changes (but only in the given three conditions). Its ***in the execution*** of change detection that @Input changes are detected. Am I right?

Comment: And how would you change input value without any of those in the first place? + change detection does not rerender the content of component but rather marks them for rerendering IF reevaluated statements ins the template (eg ngIfs fors inputs, everything) yelds different results then in the last run. This is why for example if you modify array used in ngFor with push(), it will not be (normally, without eg trackBy) detected as array evaluation in the template yelds the same array reference. But the check itself have been done whatsoever. There is just no need to get into the children.

Comment: @Antoniossss I agree that input values can't be changed in the absence of the three conditions. My point is  that only *during* "change detection", can Input changes be detected. Such changes don't *trigger* change detection, unlike the first quote says

Comment: I think it means little bit different thing. Quote regarding input says that there will be no effort to detect changes in the component if no change in the inputs *has been detected* - but that already happens in the change detection cycle due to 1 of 3 possible triggers. So change detection cycle is triggered, but it (change detector) will not go down the component tree if inputs didn't change. This is for performance reasons.

Comment: Plus remember that you have a component lifecycle hooks bound to the change detection cycle. Those will NOT be invoked (like ngOnChanges). I think this "sub change detection run" is what it is meant there.

Comment: @Antoniossss *"but it (change detector) will not go down the component tree if inputs didn't change"* - but I've read that CD runs on all components in the tree. [This](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-change-detection-strategy-onpush-and-default-strategy-edd8d41ba9ef) shows that it even runs when the child component doesn't have any attribute binding (and that's why you should use OnPush strategy on such child components)